# PHP session data not persisting

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

**FOR THE TL;DR VERSION...GO TO THE BOTTOM AND READ WHAT'S IN BOLD**

OK, so I've had this problem for a while, and I've done a lot of research, made some changes and still have no idea what is wrong with my code. My problem is that when a user submits the registration form, the session always reverts back to empty. Here is how the logic goes:
1. The user navigates to mysite/register/ and is served with register.php by index.php in that same directory.
2. index.php handles everything (calls classes for the logic and things of that nature, but everything is run through index.php at the top level)
3. The user submits the login form through a vanilla.js ajax call and the response is console.logged back out. 

Now that you understand the logic...let me get you to the code:
Here is index.php:

```
<?php
// Allowing PHP to be strictly typed and start session
declare(strict_types=1);
session_start();

// Requiring the necessary classes
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
require_once "../model/EditSession.php";
require_once "../model/DatabaseConfig.php";
require_once "../model/ServerValidation.php";
require_once "../model/RegisterUser.php";
require_once "../model/Verify.php";

// Creating the new objects
$validatingServer = new ServerValidation();
$sessionToEdit = new EditSession();
$sessionToEdit->create_new_session_id();

// Checks the request protocol
try {
    $validatingServer->checkHttps();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    header("Location: /NotSecure.php");
}

// Setting CSRF token for protection
try {
    $csrfToken = $sessionToEdit->store_secure_key_in_session("CSRFTOKEN");
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "You have a problem setting your session. $ex";
}

// Handling a navigation to the webpage
$validatingServer->navigateToWebsite("register.php", "Register", $csrfToken);
        // For when a user submits the form
        try {
            $validatingServer->checkRequestType("POST");
            $validatingServer->checkContentType("application/json");
            $registerFormData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
            $csrfTokenFromForm = $registerFormData["csrfToken"];
            $csrfTokenFromSession = $sessionToEdit->get_from_session("CSRFTOKEN");
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "Bad request data. $ex";
        }
        //$validatingServer->checkToken($csrfTokenFromForm, $csrfTokenFromSession);

        // Call to make original register user object
        try {
            $register = new RegisterUser($registerFormData["firstName"], $registerFormData["lastName"], $registerFormData["email"], $registerFormData["password"]);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }

        // Check email and register the user
        try {
            $register->checkEmail();
            $register->register();
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }

        // Sending registration email to the user
        try {
            $register->sendRegistrationEmail("http://localhost/");
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }

        echo "Successful Register";
```

Here is the frontend

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

<title><?=$pageTitle;?></title>

</head>

<body>

<main>

<form id="registerForm">
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" autocomplete="given-name" placeholder="First Name" pattern="^[A-Za-z.\s_-]+$" autofocus required>
<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" autocomplete="family-name" placeholder="Last Name" pattern="^[A-Za-z.\s_-]+$" required>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" placeholder="Email" required>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*]).{8,}" required>
<input type="hidden" id="csrfToken" value="<?=$csrfToken;?>">
<button type="submit" id="registerSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>

</main>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is index.js

```
const registerForm = document.getElementById("registerForm");
registerForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    const lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    const csrfToken = document.getElementById("csrfToken").value;
    const registerFormData = {
        "firstName":firstName,
        "lastName":lastName,
        "email":email,
        "password":password,
        "csrfToken":csrfToken
    };
    const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "index.php");
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    ajax.withCredentials = true;
    ajax.send(JSON.stringify(registerFormData));
    ajax.onload = function() {
        console.log(this.response);
    }
}, false);
```

Here is EditSession.php

```
<?php 
declare(strict_types=1);
class EditSession {

    private $firstPartOfNewId;
    private $secondPartOfNewId;
    private $thirdPartOfNewId;
    private $newSID;
    public $secureKey = "";

    // Create new session ID
    function create_new_session_id() : void {

        if (isset($_SESSION)) {
            $firstPartOfNewId = str_replace(array(".", ":"), "", $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
            $secondPartOfNewId = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
            $thirdPartOfNewId = hash("sha512", random_bytes(64));
            $newSID = $firstPartOfNewId.$secondPartOfNewId.$thirdPartOfNewId;
            session_id($newSID);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Session is not set");
        }

    }

    // Store a value in a set session
    function store_in_session(string $key,string $value) : void {

        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            throw new Exception("Session is not set.");
        }

        if (!isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }

    }

    // Store a value in a set session
    function store_secure_key_in_session(string $key) : string {

        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            throw new Exception("Session is not set.");
        }

        if (!isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            $secureKey = hash("sha512", random_bytes(64));
            $_SESSION[$key] = $secureKey;
            return $secureKey;
        } else {
            return $secureKey;
        }

    }

    // Unsetting variable associated with the $key
    function unset_session_variable(string $key) : void {

        if (isset($_SESSION)) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = "";
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Session with key is not set.");
        }

    }

    // Getting associated key from session
    function get_from_session(string $key) : string {

        if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            return $_SESSION[$key];
        } elseif (isset($_SESSION)) {
            throw new Exception("Session is set, but the key passed is not set in the session.");
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Session is not set.");
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Here is ServerValidation.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
class ServerValidation {

    // Handles navigation to website
    function navigateToWebsite(string $page, string $pageTitle, string $csrfToken) : void {
        if (empty($_POST) && empty($_GET) && empty(file_get_contents("php://input"))) {
            $csrfToken = $csrfToken;
            $pageTitle = $pageTitle;
            include_once $page;
            exit;
        }
    }

    // Checks if the website is served over https or its localhost
    function checkHttps() : void {
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] !== "https" && $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] !== "localhost") {
            throw new Exception("Not served over https");
        }
    }

    // Checks if the content type is what it should be
    function checkContentType(string $type) : void {
        if ($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] !== $type) {
            throw new Exception("Wrong content-type");
        }
    }

    // Checks request method
    function checkRequestType(string $type) : void {
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] !== $type) {
            throw new Exception("Wrong request method");
        }
    }

    function checkToken(string $tokenFromFrontend, string $tokenFromSession) : void {
        if ($tokenFromSession !== $tokenFromFrontend) {
            throw new Exception("Tokens not matching up, there is a problem!!");
        }
    }

}
```

Now, here is what happens with the code. When the user submits the register form, with the csrfToken that is fetched from the hidden value in the form using AJAX, I get an exception thrown in my program (specifically from the `checkToken()` method in the ServerValidation class) that says "tokens not matching up". And I have confirmed why this is. If I var_dump the $_SESSION right after I call session_start(), it is **ALWAYS** empty. It doesn't matter if it has already been initialized (by the user first navigating to the page), it is ALWAYS empty. And so, following the logic of the program, it inserts a new value for CSRFTOKEN and so of course they don't match up. I am absolutely stumped and have been working on this problem for a week. Here are some answers to questions I know will be asked:
1. I'm using a macbook running XAMPP and php 7.2
2. My cookies are set to http_only, but not secure_only. All other cookie parameters are default.
3. My file permissions where my session data is being stored (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/) is 777 (I just wanted to do something I know would work)
4. What happens if I don't create a new php session_id? The same outcome will happen...ie - the session will still **always** be initialized as empty
5. Can I var_dump the session at different points in the program? Sure...here are different points and their outcomes:
- Right after session_start is called:
    - When the user initially navigates to the page: an empty session.
    - When the user has submitted the registration form: an empty session

- Right after `$csrfToken = $sessionToEdit->store_secure_key_in_session("CSRFTOKEN");` is called:
    - When the user initially navigates to the page: a session with the key of CSRFTOKEN is returned
    - When the user has submitted the registration form: a session with the key of CSRFTOKEN is returned (but the value is different than when the user originally navigated to the page)

- Right after `$validatingServer->navigateToWebsite("register.php", "Register", $csrfToken);`
    - When the user initially navigates to the page: Nothing, because the program doesn't get that far because it exits out.
    - When the user has submitted the registration form: a session with the key of CSRFTOKEN is returned (but the value is different than when the user originally navigated to the page and the value is different than what lives in the hidden field in the registration form)

Here is the question: **Why do my session values keep initializing to empty, even though I'm on the same domain, doing all my work in the same file, have my session parameters set right, and have my file permissions set right?**

Comment: Have you verified the client sends the session id back properly?

Comment: @CBroe what method are you talking about?

Comment: Whichever one you like ...? Now sure what the question is now.

Comment: @CBroe well like what do you mean, make sure the client is sending back the right session id?

Comment: Yes, of course (_and_ that it is also properly received inside the server-side script) ... since that is the basis for sessions working properly, it should also be the first thing you check.

Comment: @CBroe so I've checked that, and the answer is no. That's why the session is initializing as empty every time